# How to read both from both ANSI and Unicode encoded files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, ansi

I am trying to write a function using Python where the user inputs the root directory and the key phrases to search for. Then my function searches the entire directory to find and output lines from files that contain the key phrases that were inputted. Currently, my script is able to read and output lines from files encoded with ANSI, but not Unicode. Please let me know how I may change my code so my script can search through both types of encoded files. I am relatively new to Python, thanks!

My Python script:

```
import os

def myFunction(rootdir, keyPhrases):

    path = rootdir # Enter the root directory you want to search from

    key_phrases = [keyPhrases] # Enter here the key phrases in the lines you hope to find 
    key_phrases = [i.replace('\n','') for i in key_phrases] #In case an \n is added to the end of the string when the parameter is passed to the function

    # This for loop allows all sub directories and files to be searched
    for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(path): 
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.log')] # Specify here the format of files you hope to search from (ex: ".txt" or ".log")
        files.sort() # file is sorted list

        files = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files] # Joins the path and the name, so the files can be opened and scanned by the open() function

        # The following for loop searches all files with the selected format
        for filename in files:

                # Opens the individual files and to read their lines
                with open(filename) as f:
                    f = f.readlines()

                # The following loop scans for the key phrases entered by the user in every line of the files searched, and stores the lines that match into the "important" array
                for line in f:
                    for phrase in key_phrases: 
                        if phrase in line:
                            print(line)
                            break 

    print("The end of the directory has been reached, if no lines are printed then that means the key phrase does not exist in the root directory you entered.")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded with Unicode"? Or, for that matter, "encoded with ANSI"? Do you mean UTF-16-LE and whatever the (Windows) OEM 8-bit charset is?

Comment: Try: `with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Comment: As a side note: look up the help for `str.endswith`: it can take a tuple of suffixes to check for all at once, instead of needing a separate `endswith` check for each one.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the response. When I tried your solution I got "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte." Do you know how I may solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Abertnert and thank you for your response. I'm not too sure what you mean by UTF-16-LE and OEM 8 bit charset. When I check the encoding by opening the file in notepad and clicking save as, the encoding shows as either ANSI or Unicode. Thank you for the side note, I'll try to use str.endswith rather than two endswith statements.

Comment: @D.Wu. You'll need something like [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-detecting-encodings-of-multiple-files) to detect the encoding of arbitrary files.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for the suggestion, I just downloaded chardet-3.0.4.tar.gz to my python 3.6 folder and the folder of my python script. However, when I "import chardet" in my Python script, visual studio identifies it as an error saying that it's unable to import chardet. Do you mind telling me how to fix this issue and make proper use of it please? Thanks!

Comment: @D.Wu. Get rid of visual studio and use a proper python IDE. Or just write the code with a standard text editor and run the code in a command window.

Comment: Unicode is what Windows Notepad calls UTF16. Use `utf16` to open it.  If using Visual Studio, install Python Tools for Windows for Python support.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows "Unicode" (UTF16) encoded files the first 2 bytes are usually a byte order marker (BOM) with value 0xFF 0xFE. This indicates UTF16 little endian encoding. "ANSI" (typically Windows-1252) files have no marker.

When you try to read a UTF16 file as though it were encoded with a different 8 bit encoding, e.g. UTF8, Windows-1252, or ASCII you will see a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception because 0xFF is not a valid byte in these encodings (or a valid start byte for UTF-8).

So, if you know for certain that the files will be either UTF-16-LE or Windows-1252 encoded, then you could test for a UTF16 BOM at the start of the file and open the file with that encoding, if detected:

```
import sys
from codecs import BOM_UTF16_LE

def get_file_encoding(filename, default=None):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if f.read(2) == BOM_UTF16_LE:
            return 'utf_16'
        return default if default else sys.getdefaultencoding()

with open(filename, encoding=get_file_encoding(filename, 'windows_1252')) as f:
    for line in f:
        for phrase in key_phrases: 
            if phrase in line:
                print(line)
                break
```

Also, you might consider using regular expressions for the phrase matching instead of looping over the possible phrases.